# Example code for catching Crystal Reports exception in C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a client application that sets some parameters and report source on a crystal reports 2011 ReportViewer object and I want to catch error messages and display meaningful errors.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288423(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
      report.Load ("c:\\sample.rpt");
      report.PrintToPrinter (1,true,1,2);
   }
   catch (LogOnException engEx)
   {
      MessageBox.Show _
("Incorrect Logon Parameters. Check your user name and password.");
   }
   catch (DataSourceException engEx)
   {
   MessageBox.Show _
("An error has occurred while connecting to the database.");
   }
   catch (EngineException engEx)
   {
      MessageBox.Show (engEx.Message);
   }
}
```